# How to remove numbers from text strings in excel cells

Tags: python, excel, excel-2016, cell-formatting

I have an Excel workbook with header cells such as the following:

1. birthday 645 (before 1995)
2. birthday (after 1995) 99

...

...

I want to remove every number in those cells except for the ones that are needed to be there. In the example above, except for 1995, any other numbers in those cells should be removed.

Is there a way that I can do such a thing? such as defining a function in Python?

Comment: how is excel supposed to know what numbers to keep?

Comment: I know that, you are right about that, but the problem here is that my database contains more 600 columns and it would take me a long time I do it manually. Maybe a Code in Python?

Comment: You would still need to come up with a rule as to when to keep a number and when not to.  If you cannot define such rules, then it does not matter the language, it will not be possible.

Comment: @ScottCraner well I noticed that the numbers that should be kept are all located within parenthesis and the numbers that must be removed are at the beginning of the text string except for a few exceptions which can be handled manually

Comment: @Alirezaro93 Are all of the parentheses well defined? i.e. There are no '(( before 1995)' or '()))' or 'birth(day 695 (before 1995)'?

Comment: @LoganRowe Yes, they are well defined fortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments above, assuming well defined parentheses, you can use this function to remove all numbers that are not nested in parentheses.

```py
def remove_nums(string):
    depth = 0
    res = []
    for char in string:
        if char.isdigit() and depth == 0:
            continue
        elif char == '(':
            depth += 1
        elif char == ')':
            depth -= 1
        res.append(char)
        
    string = ''.join(res)
        
    # remove double spaces
    while '  ' in string:
        string = string.replace('  ', ' ')
        
    return string

if __name__ == "__main__":
    strings = ["birthday 645 (before 1995)", "birthday (after 1995) 99"]
    for string in strings:
        print(string+':',remove_nums(string))
```

```
In:  "birthday 645 (before 1995)"
Out: "birthday (before 1995)"
In:  "birthday (after 1995) 99"
Out: "birthday (after 1995)"
```